# What is the easiest way to store a variable in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, html, local-storage

I am migrating my script from Google Chrome Extension to node.js

And I simply need to store a couple of variables, nothing fancy and performance isn't an issue either, since they would only be accessed when the script is restarted.

In Google Chrome Extension I would use the client side HTML5 storage (localStorage)

However as a server language node.js doesn't have this feature and it's not surprising.

I could of course install some database and being particularly familiar with MySQL this is not an issue, but, if there is a simple way of storing my configs - I would much like to try it out.

Comment: Simplest would probably be to load/store from a JSON file if it's not much data and it's specific to the app instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If u get experience with localStorage you can use [node-localstorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-localstorage).

Comment: Never seen this before, looks neat.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `sw-precache`, aka service workers. They run in the browser and can be used by the fetch api. Here's a great node_module that will accomplish your needs.
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache

[image]

Here is a codelab that explains service workers in more detail:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/sw-precache/index.html